# Import module that contains main module functions

Tags: python

Suppose I have this folder structure:

```
  module
      module.py
      __init__.py
  main.py
```

Main.py imports module.py which itself should have functions that are only present in main.py. For example, main.py code:

```
  from module import *

  def foo(var):
      print var

  module.foo_module()
```

Content of module.py:

```
   def foo_module():
       foo("Hello world!")
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this without repeating the functions? If not, how can I import main.py into module.py?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is an object in python, including functions. You can pass the necessary function as an argument. Whether this makes sense in your case, I don't have enough information to know.

```
def foo(var):
    print var

module.foo_module(foo)

def foo_module(foo):
    foo("Hello world!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid circular imports. You could do that here by placing `foo` in `module`.

If you don't want `foo` in `module`, you could instead create a separate module `bar` to hold `foo`, and import `bar` in both `main` and `module`.

Comment: I know but what I want to do is far more complex than this example

Comment: It doesn't matter how complex. There is never an advantage to using circular imports!

Comment: What if I create a new module with the common functions. Would it be possible to be called from both main.py and module.py?
If so, is it just a matter of adding a new folder in the same dir as main.py called "common" with an __init__.py on it?

Comment: Yes, provided the directory containing `main.py` is in `sys.path`. That can be done by listing it in your `PYTHONPATH`.